# Error[Pe020]: identifier "FILE" is undefined in IAR Workbench

Tags: file, compiler-errors, stderr, iar

```
// Preprocessor directive mention in <> formate :
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "math.h"
#include "string.h"
#include "limits.h"
#include "stddef.h"
#include "stdint.h"
...
int main()
{
 FILE *fin, *fout;  //Error[Pe020]: identifier "FILE" is undefined
 ...
 ...
 ...
 fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", opus_get_version_string());              
                         //Error[Pe020]: identifier "stderr" is undefined 

}
```

As per above code I got an two Errors :

1) **"Error[Pe020]: identifier "FILE" is undefined"**

when I found stdlib.h then there are no any kind of "FILE" directive define or typedef.
   So,please tell me which changes needed in stdlib.h or stdio.h

2) **Error[Pe020]: identifier "stderr" is undefined**

So,In which header file stderr define ?

Please tell me How to solve above errors ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, `FILE` is in `stdio.h` not in `stdlib.h`. Second, the default library does not include `FILE` support since this feature uses a lot of space and is seldom needed in embedded systems. To use `FILE` you must switch to full libraries in the configuration dialog (if you use the IDE) or by using the command line switch `--dlib full` (if you use the compiler from the command line).

Note that the full library is much larger than the normal library so if the only use of `FILE` is to print diagnostic messages to `stderr` I suggest that you use some other way of presenting the messages.

Comment: In the IDE: Project Options >GeneralOptions > Library Configuration > Library > Full

Answer (score 0):

FILE is defined in **stdio.h** standard header file. As **Johan** mentioned the default library configuration in IAR IDE does not include full Dlib support.
We can change to Full Dlib support under project options.
Project options shall be opened with **ALT + F7** Hotkey or **project tab and then options**. Check this Image.
[Project Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z58or.jpg)